# How to filter data using multiple criteria (with one line) in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-2016

I am trying to filter data by not clicking check marks but just putting row of choices in one line.

For example, instead of clicking individual checkmarks such as C100005136, C100005150, C100005152 and C100005153, I would like to just put these value in one line in somewhere.

For example:
**C100005136, C100005150, C100005152, C100005153**

Possible solution I am looking for is in one line or it could be in multiple rows..

Anyway to copy and paste data of choices is what I am looking for.

[image]

Is this possible in Excle2016?

Comment: You could do that in VBA, but it won't be pretty.

Answer (score 1):

Put the values into a cell 'somewhere' then split the cell's value on the delimiter into a variant and use the variant for Criteria1 with operation:=xlfiltervalues.

```
dim var as variant
var = split(cells(1, "A").value, ", ")
columns("B").autofilter field:=1, criteria1:=var, operation:=xlfiltervalues
```

Comment: Where do you put this code? Do you have any example in other site by chance?